# How to iterate through all lines in "line-by-line" npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, text-files, line

As a temporary method, I use a .txt file to store certain variables of my program. Writing goes perfectly with `fs.appendFile`, but given the size of it, reading with `fs.readFile` is not suitable - I'd like to get **a certain line** from the file, and [npm line-by-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line) was told me may help.

I'm a bit lost with it, though. This is a function I call:

```
function LBL_SetValueToLine(path, lineid, value){

    var lr = new lblreader(path);
    var m = 0;

    lr.on('line', function (line) {
        // 'line' contains the current line without the trailing newline character.
        m=+1;
        if(m==lineid){ value = line; };
    });

};
```

And the call itself happens as a usual function call, with all input variable being *surely* proper.

I should have thought this is not a proper method, but the documentation said, this is the **synchronous** method. However, I can see that the work of .on is asysnc, because of the function input it needs.

Not sure if it has anything to do with the problem, but anyways, `console.log` after the function call always indicated that the variable hasn't been changed.

How can I do it?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but if you are asking for how to make this synchronous then [that's impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572?how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Readline`](https://nodejs.org/docs/v4.4.0/api/readline.html) module that is provided by the Core Node API.

> ## Readline API Example for Line-by-Line
>
> ```
> const readline = require('readline');
> const fs = require('fs');
>
> const rl = readline.createInterface({
>   input: fs.createReadStream('sample.txt')
> });
>
> rl.on('line', (line) => {
>   console.log('Line from file:', line);
> });
> ```

The example above was taken from the [Node Readline API Docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/v4.4.0/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line)

Comment: At first, I was scared, because my first assumption was that `rl.on` needs some complex asnyc way to call - I should have thought it over when I saw that `line-by-line` does the same way, but anyways, I have to ask: **does it needs async call?** Does it go on with executing the code after establishing `rl.on`, or it waits until it is "closed"?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't block your code after `rl.on()` is set to listen. There is the `close` event which essentially is the equivalent of an async callback. If you need more control flow you'll need to implement some other library to wrap this in like `bluebird` or `async`.

Comment: Ah, great...do I think well, that a bigger NodeJS app is full of these **callback within the callback of my callback** situations?

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt I'm not sure I understand what your last comment is trying to say

Comment: It's a bit hard to put into other context, though. The matter is that I'm implementing `rl.on` and this is the third callback I write. First it was a jQuery AJAX request. Within its callback there's Readline, and within its callback another HTTP request is coming. So, it's quite nested. In the past, I thought it's rather rare in NodeJS.

Comment: Anyways, I was successful with ReadLine, so thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The variable didn't change because the `videoid` was passed in by value. This means that any change to it within the function is not reflected on the variable itself.

For example:

```
function increment(num) {
  num++;
}
var a = 1;
increment(a);
console.log(a); // 1
```

To pass in a variable that would be changed by the function, you'll need to pass in an object type.

For example:

```
function increment(num) {
  num.val++;
}
var a = {val: 1};
increment(a);
console.log(a); // Object {val: 2}
```

To apply this to your program, you'll need to create an object to hold the `videoid` as well as close the stream when you're done reading:

```
var videodata = {videoid: 'someID'};
function YTAPP_LBL_SetValueToLine(path, lineid, viddata){

  var lr = new lblreader(path);
  var m = 0;

  lr.on('line', function (line) {
    // 'line' contains the current line without the trailing newline character.
    m += 1;
    if(m == lineid){ 
      viddata.videoid = line;

      // Close the stream
      lr.close();
    }
  });



};
```

Comment: Wow, wait...how is it possible that `a` is enough to add as parameter instead of `a.val`?